# MySQL query why does my INNER JOIN group date result

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have the following database tables and columns:

```
students
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
| student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
|         95 | John              | Doe              |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+

studentcourseplan
+--------+------------+
| cpl_id | student_id |
+--------+------------+
|    209 |         95 |
|    273 |         95 |
+--------+------------+

studentdates
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| student_id | student_startdate | student_enddate |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|         95 | 2012-07-02        | 2012-08-17      |
|         95 | 2012-08-20        | 2012-11-16      |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

If I run this query...

```
SELECT 
    scp.cpl_id,
    s.student_id,
    s.student_firstname,
    s.student_lastname,
    sd.student_startdate,
    sd.student_enddate
FROM
    studentcourseplan scp
        INNER JOIN
    students s ON s.student_id = scp.student_id
        INNER JOIN
    studentdates sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id
```

... I get the following output:

```
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| cpl_id | student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname | student_startdate | student_enddate |
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 209    |         95 | John              | Doe              | 2012-07-02        | 2012-08-17      |
| 273    |         95 | John              | Doe              | 2012-07-02        | 2012-08-17      |
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Notice the dates from result compared to the values in the table `studentdates`. They are wrong. I want something like the following output instead:

```
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| cpl_id | student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname | student_startdate | student_enddate |
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 209    |         95 | John              | Doe              | 2012-07-02        | 2012-08-17      |
| 273    |         95 | John              | Doe              | 2012-08-20        | 2012-11-16      |
+--------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check your question about your database schema, because as it stands, it looks wrong in respect of the relations you would like to materialize in your query

Comment: How do you know that `cpl_id 209` belongs to `start_date '2012-07-02'` and not to `'2012-08-20'` ?

Comment: @Grisha ohh. Did not think of that, thank's for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map `cpl_id` with `studentdates`. You can add one column to `studentdates` called cpl_id & then change the query accordingly.

Comment: Hmm that's not really an option. There are to much data to edit manualy. Do you know any other option?

Comment: if in your program, start date is related to course plan (means start date of particular course is the start date for student opting that course) than you can put `startdate` in `studentcourseplan` creating one more column. That may reduce manual editing.